# Git утратилась информация

Tags: git

Проблема: исчезла информация для комитов (т е изменения).

Что я делал (по не опытности...обычно гит юзаю закомитил..запушил...смержил...ну в обще в таком духе):

1) Работаю в студии VS 2019 + расширение для GitLab.

2) В ней есть опция `удержать` (`stash` если в консоли).

3) после чего я понял, что это не то, что мне нужно и поробовал восстановить (такую кнопочку и нажал - какие консольные команды выполнялись в этот момент я не знаю).

4) Операция не выполнилась, и я увидел ошибку `stash applay` и красный крести (больше ничего)...секунд 5 после покрутилось колесико (типо студия задумалась). После чего она сама выключилась.

5) Я запускаю студию, и удержанных файлов нет...просто нет и все

6) Команда `git stash list` с командной строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т. е. пустота.

Был какой то откат до старого коммита (АВТОМАТИЧЕСКИ). При чем не понятный...часть изменений осталась, часть тупо пропала.

Чисто так логически думая `git` должен был хранить где то инфу...те есть он либо удали файл свой и новый создал, либо перезатер инфу....

Вопрос: Можно ли что-то пробовать в качесте восстановления

можете предлагать все что в голову влезет....

Если нужна какая-нибудь информация еще , говорите, я предоставлю.

Comment: `git reflog` - может что-то найдётся если были коммиты. Но вообще, если файлы не коммитились вообще, то вряд ли до них теперь можно добраться. Если стеш всё же создавался, а потом удалился, то вроде он там будет в списке. Ну а дальше выкачивать по хэшу и смотреть.

Comment: @Qwertiy `git log -g` показывает то же самое, только поточнее, с временем (указывает на 13 декабря). Как я понимаю - это окончатель показывает что восстановление с помощью гита не возможно?

Comment: @Qwertiy тут еще момент..возможно посмотреть с точки зрения админов и винды...мб можно как то достать измененный файл?...удаленные уже проверил - то что нужно, не нашел.

Comment: Я не знаю. Можно попытаться найти удалённые файлы, но я не думаю, что он удаляет их.

Comment: git fsck --no-reflog, покажет висящее хеши коммитов, можно потом по контенту проверить, есть ли там нужный сташнутый

Comment: @Exploding я попробовал...на самом деле есть несколько вещей...но к сожелению последнии 7... больше вытащить никак нельзя?

Comment: ну тогда хз, если в списке dangling commit нет, скорее всего ченжи утеряны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть очень отличная команда:

`gitk --all $(git fsck --no-reflog | Select-String "(dangling commit )(.*)" | %{ $_.Line.Split(' ')[2] })`

Она решила мою проблему.
Проверено под Windows (запускал с PS).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подсмотренно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git#34666995)

Остается нажать ПКМ по `WIP` и выбрать `Create new branch`, в которой после появятся утерянные изменения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]